# Check irreducibility of polynomials in a field/ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

$$x^2+x-2$$ in $$\mathbb F_3[x], \mathbb F_7[x]$$

I tried to find roots for the equation and found x=1, -2 then it is reducible in both. Is it the correct way to address reducibility?

Comment: For polynomials of degree $\le3$ checking for the presence/absence of roots is sufficient. For a bit extra you may notice that $1=-2\pmod3$, so over $\Bbb{F}_3$ this polynomial has a double root. This was just on the side. Your observation proves that it is reducible all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, since a polynomial has a linear factor $(x-a)$ if and only if it admits $a$ as a root because of the following identity : 
$$
f(x) = g(x)(x-a) + f(a)
$$
(where $g(x)$ is the factor obtained by the Euclidean algorithm), then yes, your procedure is correct. In general, it is possible that a polynomial admits no root but is still reducible ; for instance, if a polynomial is a product of two irreducible quadratics, then it will be a reducible polynomial of degree $4$ with no roots.

Hope that helps,